# ConcurrentModificationException when updating JavaFX Tree in the background

Tags: java, javafx-2

My code creates `TreeItem<String>`  in a background task since I have a lot of them and their creation takes a considerable amount of time in which the application freezes. In this example it doesn't make much sense but it illustrates the problem I run into in my actual application. When expanding nodes the program throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

I use jdk1.7.0_17 and JavaFX 2.2.7

Does anyone know how to create a thread-safe `Tree` or how to circumvent the problem?

### Exception

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper$ObservableListIterator.next(ObservableListWrapper.java:681)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.updateExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:788)
    ...
```

### Code

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class ConcurrentExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(createNode("root"));
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    Random r = new SecureRandom();

    public TreeItem<String> createNode(final String b) {
        return new TreeItem<String>(b) {
            private boolean isLeaf;
            private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
            private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

            @Override
            public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
                if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
                    isFirstTimeChildren = false;
                    buildChildren(super.getChildren());
                }
                return super.getChildren();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLeaf() {
                if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                    isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
                    isLeaf = r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean();
                }
                return isLeaf;
            }

            private void buildChildren(final ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> children) {
                if (!this.isLeaf()) {
                    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                            int i;
                            int max = r.nextInt(500);
                            for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
                                children.addAll(new TreeItem[]{createNode("#" + r.nextInt())});
                            }
                            return i;
                        }
                    };
                    new Thread(task).start();
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current answers do not help. The point is that you have to execute the update of the children in the main Thread with the help of Platform.runLater

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class Example extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(createNode("root"));
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    Random r = new SecureRandom();

    public TreeItem<String> createNode(final String b) {
        return new TreeItem<String>(b) {
            private boolean isLeaf;
            private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
            private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

            @Override
            public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
                if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
                    isFirstTimeChildren = false;
                    buildChildren(super.getChildren());
                }
                return super.getChildren();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLeaf() {
                if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                    isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
                    isLeaf = r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean();
                }
                return isLeaf;
            }

            private void buildChildren(final ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> children) {
                if (!this.isLeaf()) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int i;
                            int max = r.nextInt(500);
                            for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
                                children.addAll(new TreeItem[]{createNode("#" + r.nextInt())});
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This guy here ran into the same problem: http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/12/handling-threads-concurrency-in-javafx/

Comment: For my use-case, I found it helpful to know that "**The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted.** A runnable passed into the runLater method will be executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to runLater. If this method is called after the JavaFX runtime has been shutdown, the call will be ignored: the Runnable will not be executed and no exception will be thrown." (https://www.irif.fr/~yunes/cours/annexes/java/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly modify anything that effects active nodes and data related to the scene graph (and that includes the items of a TreeView) from any thread other than the JavaFX application thread.

See the [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) documentation for sample tasks (the ones which return an ObservableList or Partial Results) which will help you solve your issue.  You need to create your new TreeItems in your Task in a new ObservableList and then, once the Task is finished (and on the JavaFX application thread), set the item list for your tree to the ObservableList returned from the Task.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Here is an updated version of your code which follows some of these principles and does not have any ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Why shouldn't the addAll(List) call be performed exactly in the moment where the TreeItem calls updateExpandedDescendentCount()?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class ConcurrentExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(createNode("root"));
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(treeView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  Random r = new SecureRandom();

  public TreeItem<String> createNode(final String b) {
    return new TreeItem<String>(b) {
      private boolean isLeaf;
      private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
      private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

      @Override
      public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
        if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
          isFirstTimeChildren = false;
          buildChildren(super.getChildren());
        }
        return super.getChildren();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
          isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
          isLeaf = r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean() && r.nextBoolean();
        }
        return isLeaf;
      }

      private void buildChildren(final ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> children) {
        final ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> taskChildren = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
          Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
              int i;
              int max = r.nextInt(500);
              for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
                taskChildren.addAll(new TreeItem[]{createNode("#" + r.nextInt())});
              }
              return i;
            }
          };

          task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
              children.setAll(taskChildren);
            }
          });
          new Thread(task).start();
        }
      }
    };
  }

}
```

---

*Update - Description of why the solution works*

The solution above cannot receive a `ConcurrentModificationException` because the `ObservableLists` involved are never modified concurrently.

- The `taskChildren` collections are only modified on the user thread for the task AND
- Children of tree items actively attached to the scenegraph are only modified on the JavaFX application thread for the task.

This is ensured by the following items:

1. `taskChildren.addAll` is invoked in the task's `call` method.
2. A task's call method is invoked on the user thread.
3. `children.setAll(taskChildren)` is invoked on the JavaFX application thread.
4. The JavaFX system ensures that the `onSucceeded` event handler for a task is invoked on the JavaFX application thread.
5. After task completion, no more children will ever be added to a given `taskChildren` list and the list is never modified.
6. For every task undertaken a new `taskChildren` list is created, so a given `taskChildren` list is never shared between tasks.
7. Every time a modification is made to the tree, a new task is created.
8. Task semantics are such that a given task can only be run once and never restarted.
9. The children of the TreeItem attached to the active scenegraph are only modified on the JavaFX application thread after the task has successfully completed and stopped processing.

> Why shouldn't the `addAll(List)` call be performed exactly in the moment where the `TreeItem` calls `updateExpandedDescendentCount()`?

`updateExpandedDescendentCount()` is not part of the public `TreeItem` api - it is an internal implementation method for the `TreeView` and is irrelevant to solving this problem.

---

*Update Partial Updates*

The [JavaFX Task documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) has a solution for "A Task Which Returns Partial Results".  Using something similar, you should be able to solve the issue that "the application is unusable in the beginning as one has to wait for the 'buildChildren'-thread to finish to see any nodes.".  This is because the partial result solution will allow the results to be "streamed" in small batches from the builder task thread back to the FX application thread.

This kind of solution is more complicated in implementation than the one I provided above, but should allow you to have a responsive UI that fits your requirements.  As always, when dealing with concurrent situations, extra care will need to be taken to ensure that shared data is not mutated concurrently causing potential race conditions as you experienced in your original post.

Comment: I added a description of why the attached solution works by design and not by luck.

Comment: @jewelsead: Point 5 is the important point. It seems to me that ``updateExpandedDescendentCount()`` is called at some point in time after a ``TreeItem`` has been added by the ``TreeView`` logic. When a new node is added during these 'post-add-item'-operations we get the ``ConcurrentModificationException``. So by addAll()ing the ``TreeItems`` in a single operation one will never cause the exception.
---
That solves the issue of the freezing application. But nevertheless the application is unusable in the beginning as one has to wait for the 'buildChildren'-thread to finish to see any nodes.

Comment: Added some additional suggestions on how you may use partial updates to solve the issue: "the application is unusable in the beginning as one has to wait for the 'buildChildren'-thread to finish to see any nodes".

Comment: Your answer was a godsend, @jewelsea. Helped me answer my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072114/javafx-concurrentmodificationexception-while-adding-treeitem-objects-in-treevie

Answer (score -1):

It is straightforward: you continue to update collection when the client code starts iterating it.

Remove the thread or make sure it is finished before iterator is created, or make some kind of synchronization.

Comment: I know what happens. But:
It is required for me to update the ``Tree`` in the background as my actual application may have around 20000 ``TreeItem`` on top-level and it takes a considerable amount of time to create them. During that time the application is inresponsive. So the natural way of circumventing this is to create a background thread to create the nodes.

Some kind of synchronization... of course but how?


Sorry but none of your proposals is helpful to me.